# Answer with Title on Same Line

Tags: r

Wrote the following function:

```
printVecInfo <- function(a)
{
 medianA <- data.frame("median")
  medianA <- median(a)
 return
 cat("Median:",median(medianA),"Mean:", mean(medianA),sep="\n")
}
```

When I run the function it displays the answer like this with the answer under the title:

```r
Median:
4
Mean:
4
```

How do I make it display like this with the answer beside the title?

```r
Median: 4
Mean: 4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While your code may be syntactically correct it doesn’t make much sense from a semantic point of view.

Here are some comments/advice:

1. `medianA <- data.frame("median")` creates a `data.frame` with a single `character` entry `"median"` in a single column. I don't know what the point of this is.
2. You then re-define this variable (making the previous definition obsolete) as `median <- median(a)` of (what I assume is a) `numeric` vector `a` that is passed as the function argument; this returns a scalar, i.e. a single number.
3. In the last code line you calculate `median(medianA)` and `mean(medianA)` which doesn’t make sense as `medianA` is a scalar (not a vector); to make it explicit: what you're calculating here is `median(4)` and `mean(4)` which will trivially return `4` for both cases.
4. Lastly, I encourage you to use proper indentation/spacing and familiarise yourself with how to write custom functions in R; for example, R functions can use *implicit* return values as the last evaluated expression of the function; or you can use an *explicit* return argument as `return(expression)`. Either way, anything after `return(...)` will not get evaluated.

So if you wanted to define a function that prints (and returns) the `median` and `mean` of a `numeric` vector you could write something like

```
printVecInfo <- function(x) {
   cat(sprintf("Mean of x: %f\n", mean(x)))
   cat(sprintf("Median of x: %f\n", median(x)))
   return(list(mean = mean(x), median = median(x)))
}
printVecInfo(1:5)
#Mean of x: 3.000000
#Median of x: 3.000000
#$mean
#[1] 3
#
#$median
#[1] 3
```

Comment: Maurits, thank you for your critique.  I've only been coding for a few months, so I know that my code is probably extremely sloppy even though I might end up with the right answer.  I want to continue to improve, so I really appreciate you going through and making corrections.

Comment: @Chappy `sprintf` is a wrapper for the C function `sprintf` which allows you to format text and variable values. In this case `sprintf("Mean of x: %f\n", x)` means print a string `"Mean of x: "` followed by the value of `x` as a float `"\f"` and the newline character `"\n"`. Take a look at `?sprintf`, which contains a lot of nice examples at the bottom of the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Each `\n` creates a new line, and right now your function is adding one between each piece with the `sep = "\n"` argument.

This should work, with only one return:

```r
printVecInfo <- function(a)
{
 cat("Median:",median(a),"\nMean:", mean(a))
}
```